# How to create p2p enviroment in single laptop?

Tags: p2p

I'm developing a peer-to-peer dataspace application.

For that I want to create a peer-to-peer environment locally (on a single machine, a laptop). Is there a any method or tool to do that?

Comment: Use lots of virtual hosts that interact with each other.

Comment: Does the program support starting multiple instances on a single system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just connect it to a network, then it's on the same network as itself!**

No joke, its that easy.. It can access itself variety of ways (over the network) 
(As long as you can run 2 instances of your app on the same Computer)

- By internal IP (and port)
- By Computer Name (and port)
- By IP: 127.0.0.1 (and port)
- By external IP (and port) (if
  you router is configured to forward forward incoming traffic to your computer )
- Use a Service like [Noip.com](http://www.noip.com/) (Also Requires Router configuration)